# iTerm2 make "Alert on Next Mark" permanent

Tags: iterm2

Currently if "Alert on Next Mark" is enabled, after the command run runs this featured becomes disabled.

Is there a way to make this feature permanent so after a command "Alert on Next Mark" is still enabled?